# Does the large Mysql database affect other small Mysql databases performance?

Tags: mysql

does the large Mysql database affect other small Mysql databases performance?

Lets say I have 10 mysql databases ; one of them very large and gets hit much more than others. Does large database affect performances of small databases? Should one consider Mysql performance as a one or database based?

thank you

Comment: Unrelated. Of course, it is possible that a query to a large database removes objects belonging to other databases from caches, but this is an indirect dependency.

Comment: Not if they're on separate systems and networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sheer size of the database alone won't necessarily affect performance of other databases on the same server, but there are different levels of contention that could. If your 10 databases are all on the same server, then they're sharing hardware resources, and of course those resources aren't unlimited. One database could utilize a majority of the CPU at a given time potentially causing waits and slowness for the other databases in the interim. This is called resource contention. So long as you provision your server with enough resources, then it's not usual that this should occur.

Another kind of contention that exists within the database itself, is called table contention. This would only affect any dependencies (usually within just that database) on a particular table. For example, if a large `UPDATE` statement was being ran against the entire table, the table would be locked, and other queries trying to access the table may be waiting until the `UPDATE` statement completes.

This *could* affect other databases if you have cross-database dependencies, such as a view in one of the other databases that references the locked table in the first database. Then that view would also have to wait on the `UPDATE` statement occuring in the first database. But the contention is contained to only that locked table and the dependencies on it, such as the view in this example. It would not affect any non-dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is very little contention between databases.  J.D. covered the *system* and *database* contentions well.

There are also contentions among shared resources *within* MySQL:

- The single, main, cache ("buffer_pool")
- Table cache
- Memory allocation
- "Change buffer" (for delayed writing of secondary index updates)
- Writing to logs (eg, binlog, slowlog)
- Access to system tables (eg, `information_schema`)
- Thread cache
- Handling of transactions (they share a "log")

In general, these contentions are secondary to what JD mentioned.